# c++ returning custom class from function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector, return

it's been a while since I worked with C++, and I'm trying to write a short function to process a vector from a string of the format "{(0.00, 0.00); (1.00, 0.00); (0.00, 1.00); (1.00, 1.00)}" into a custom class.

I'm struggling, however, with successfully returning the values that I pull from the string in a custom class from a function.

Find the relevant code below:

```
class TwoDMap
{
private:
    int dim, num_verts;
    std::vector<float> int_array;
public:
    TwoDMap (int num_vertices, int dimension);
    float getData(int num_vert, int dim);
    void addData(float value);
};

TwoDMap::TwoDMap(int num_vertices, int dimension)
{
    num_verts = num_vertices;
    dim = dimension;
    int_array.reserve(num_vertices * dimension);
}

float TwoDMap::getData(int num_vert, int dimension)
{
    return int_array[(num_vert * dim) + dimension];
}

void TwoDMap::addData(float value)
{
    int_array.push_back(value);
}

void processStringVertex(TwoDMap return_vector, int vert_index, int dimension, std::string input_vertex)
{
    //Process a single portion of the string and call the addData method
    //to add individual floats to the map
}

TwoDMap processStringVector(int dimension, int num_vertices, std::string input_vector)
{
    TwoDMap array2D (num_vertices, dimension);

    //Process the whole string, calling the processStringVertex method
    //and passing in the variable array2D

    return array2D;
}

int main()
{
    std::string v = "{(0.00, 0.00); (1.00, 0.00); (0.00, 1.00); (1.00, 1.00)}";
    int dim = 2;
    int num_verts = 4;
    TwoDMap vect = processStringVector (dim, num_verts, v);

    for( int i = 0; i < num_verts; i = i + 1)
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < dim; j = j + 1)
        {
            std::cout << vect.getData(i, j) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

My string arithmetic is all returning correctly, and the code compiles and runs, but my TwoDMap class is returning all 0's in the main method loop even though the correct values are being passed down to the addData method.

After a lot of troubleshooting and debugging, I believe the issue to be in how I'm passing the custom class TwoDMap.  However, after trying several variations on this (passing a two-dimensional array, passing a one dimensional array, passing a pointer to an array, passing the TwoDMap with an internal one dimensional array, and this variation on the TwoDMap), I'm at a loss as to the correct way to perform operations in this manner.

How can I pass out a list-like object from functions written in this manner?

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: You haven't shown enough code. `addData` isn't being called in the code you've posted. It's good that you tried to cut the code down but you need to provide enough code so that someone else can compile it and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, in `processStringVector()`, that first line is a function declaration. There's no reason here to return a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the map by reference:

```
void processStringVertex(TwoDMap & return_vector, int vert_index, int dimension,
/*                              ^^^          */          std::string input_vertex)
```

If you pass it by value as you are doing at the moment, the original map (namely the local variable `array2D` in `processStringVector`) is never modified.